# change argument object in R

Tags: r, function

I want to mutate a data.frame object within a function. The following does not do what I intended:

```
# function to change factors to characters using dplyr
# x: a data.frame
fa_clean <- function(x,...) {
  require(dplyr)
  x <- x %>% mutate_if(is.factor, as.character) 
  print(x)
  return(x) 
 }

# example set 
test <- data.frame(number=c(1:10),letter=as.factor(letters[1:10]))

fa_clean(test) # applying the function 
str(test) # letter is still a factor ???
```

I am obviously missing something. Edit: And I am aware of:

```
test <- fa_clean(test)
```

But I would like to run it without this assignment.

Comment: R is a functional language. It's a _feature_ that you have to explicitly assign the result to something.

Comment: Also, `print`ing something to the console is not the same as returning a result

Comment: Would `magrittr`'s inplace pipe work for your needs?  `test %<>% mutate_if(is.factor, as.character)` will update `test` in place, although if you use that inside a function with argument `x`, it won't update `test` outside of the function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is your code with the necessary modification to make it work:

```
fa_clean <- function(x) {
  varname <- deparse(substitute(x))
  require(dplyr)
  x <- x %>% mutate_if(is.factor, as.character) 
  assign(varname, x, envir = .GlobalEnv)
}

# example set 
test <- data.frame(number=c(1:10),letter=as.factor(letters[1:10]))
fa_clean(test)
str(test) # letter is no longer a factor
'data.frame':   10 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ number: int  1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
 $ letter: chr  "a" "b" "c" "d" ...
```

Comment: Thanks, so basically removing the piping did the trick. Your first version, which I also tried before returns a factor.

Comment: fa_clean <- function(x,...) {
  require(dplyr)
  x <- x %>% mutate_if(is.factor, as.character) 
  x # don't print, just return
}

    test <- data.frame(number=c(1:10),letter=as.factor(letters[1:10]))
    fa_clean(test)
    str(test) # returns a factor

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted. I thought that I would need environments, I just fooled around with <<-, but your solution taught me a lot. Thank you very much.